# Block ICQ contact requests in Pidgin

Tags: pidgin, icq

Is there a way in Pidgin to block ICQ contact requests (not only messages) from unknown users?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [pidgin-privacy-please](https://code.google.com/archive/p/pidgin-privacy-please/) plugin for Pidgin:

> **Authorization requests**
>
> ... ... ...
>
> Or, if you already have all the
>   friends you need, you can also have
>   all authorization requests rejected
>   automatically (note that, depending on
>   the protocol, you might still be asked
>   for a reason for rejecting).